# C++ / Qt Reduce loop frequency

Tags: c++, multithreading, loops, qt, timer

I need to execute a function periodically with a maximum precision of 1ms. But in C++/Qt, timers are not enough precise. For example, when I tried on Windows 10, `msleep`, `usleep` or `nsleep` can't go under 15ms.

So I've decided to implements a `while(true)` with a `QElapsedTimer` in it. But the `while(true)` is executed around each 20 nanoseconds (maybe my measure is not very precise) and that take too much CPU than I need. It would be enough to execute it every 500µs.

Is there a mechanism to reduce the loop frequency or a library with more thread sleep precision ?
How can achieve this ? Of course the perfect solution would be `usleep(500)` but like I said, it's not working on Windows and it's reported in Qt documentation

> Note: This function does not guarantee accuracy. The application may
> sleep longer than usecs under heavy load conditions. Some OSes might
> round usecs up to 10 ms or 15 ms; on Windows, it will be rounded up to
> a multiple of 1 ms.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The most accurate timer qt C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51927666/the-most-accurate-timer-qt-c)

Comment: @Passerby No unfortunately, all timers with Signals have a bad precision when you reach low periods. Even if you put Qt::PreciseTimer, it's OS dependant.
Here is a [good article](https://blat-blatnik.github.io/computerBear/making-accurate-sleep-function/) about the problem but the `preciseSleep()` is basically my `while(true)` and take approximately the same CPU charge.

Comment: The main point in that linked page is the inherent limitation of not using a RTOS. I guess you need to define the problem more closely.  Every 500µs ± what?

Comment: I need to reach a 1ms accuracy. So I can usleep for 500µs or 800µs. I don't need µs precision on the sleep. But it takes 15ms when I test it.

Answer (score 0):

If you call [QThread::yieldCurrentThread()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#yieldCurrentThread) in your `while (true)` loop you will not see a decrease in CPU usage but your timing thread will actually not block other threads from running.